# Why does `gzip` generate different binary files when compressing the same file?

Tags: linux, gzip, tar

Here's how it compares with `bzip2`:

```
$ /tmp  ls testdir
xxx!                                                                                                                                                                                                            
$ /tmp  cat testdir/xxx\!
$ /tmp  tar -czf t1.tgz testdir                                                                                                                                                                                 
$ /tmp  tar -czf t2.tgz testdir
$ /tmp  md5sum t1.tgz
5485da4154e180b2c30cb43ed721aee9  t1.tgz
$ /tmp  md5sum t2.tgz
c494cd05ea3fd3aee997c541983423bd  t2.tgz
$ /tmp  tar -cjf t1.bz2 testdir
$ /tmp  tar -cjf t2.bz2 testdir
$ /tmp  md5sum t1.bz2                                                                                                                                                                                           
35003556c14da931e0bb31e56a8c42f9  t1.bz2
$ /tmp  md5sum t2.bz2                                                                                                                                                                                           
35003556c14da931e0bb31e56a8c42f9  t2.bz2
```

I wonder why does the name of the archive file affect the output of `gzip`.

Comment: It is not the compression algorithm that is responsible for the difference in data, but the `tar` archive command. It also stores file names and permissions and access times. Most likely the times changed between the two runs.

Comment: @arkascha Actually, gzip-compressed files do contain the original filename, which could well be different here. I don't know how tar calls gzip (or compressed internally) to be sure if that is the cause though.

Comment: @arkascha But when I use `bz2` the result doesn't seem to be affect by different archive names. If it is the case that the uncompressed tar archives are different in both cases, `bz2` should also generate different results.

Comment: @hvd AFAIK tar creates an archive wich is then gzipped on-the-fly (in stream manner).

Comment: @Satoru.Logic That is why I specifically referred to the access times. I assume that that those times have been altered between the two attempts using the gzip algorithm.

Comment: @arkascha Yes, I just noticed that, see my answer :)

Comment: @hvd So you took the inspiration from my comments, even ask for a detail and _then_ you write an answer? Wow.

Comment: @arkascha If you provide an answer with more detail and readability, I would happily use yours ;p

Comment: @arkascha No, this isn't what you wrote. You wrote about the access times of the files being compressed. It isn't about those access times. It's about the time of compression. If you decompress the two tgz files, you get bitwise-identical tar files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `file t1.tgz t2.tgz` and you should see a difference. gzip-compressed files contain a filename and modification time. The filename portion is unused on my system the way you're creating the archives, but the modification time is. If you repeatedly create the a file with one specific name, you will still get different files.